# .Net: How to do multiple languages with "Content" build type Resource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm using .Net Resource API to create Multiple languages function for my website.
I followed [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580043/How-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-Csharp)

By this way I can create embedded resource which cannot change at runtime. When I change Build type to "Content", the resource file can be changed at runtime, but I don't know how to do multiple languages with this build type. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a smilar solution for this in other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458723/3401842

You need to set default language in Global.asax by adding this function:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    }
```

If you want to use change language option for users and created change language buttons (for example EN and FR buttons). You have to set culture values in a controller. For example:

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", "SelectLanguage", "Home", new { SelectedLanguage = "en-US" }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Français", "SelectLanguage", "Home", new { SelectedLanguage = "fr-FR" }, null)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string SelectedLanguage) 
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(SelectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(SelectedLanguage.ToLower());

        HttpCookie LangCookie = new HttpCookie("LangCookie");
        LangCookie.Value = SelectedLanguage;
        Response.Cookies.Add(LangCookie);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

And also if you want to check language cookie, you can control it in your Global.asax, like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie LangCookie = Request.Cookies["LangCookie"];
        if (LangCookie != null && LangCookie.Value != null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(LangCookie.Value);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(LangCookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        }
    }
```

You may also go through this [guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com.tr/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).