# ASP.NET MVC How to Save multi language in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I need to store languages in cookies when use changes the language and read language from cookies 
The below code works great but i don't know where and how can i store language in cookies and read from cookies

This is Rout:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "DefaultLocalized",
      url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new
      {
          controller = "Home",
          action = "Index",
          id = UrlParameter.Optional,


      }
          );
```

The ActionFilterAttribute:

```
    public class EnableMultiLanguage : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public EnableMultiLanguage()
        {
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string language = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
            {

                var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == language);

                if (cultureInfo == null)
                {
                    cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] = cultureInfo.Name;

            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] = "en-US";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here how the user changes the language:

```
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "en-US" }, null)</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("French", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),new { language = "fr-FR" },null)</li>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37458723/3401842 This answer contains information about how you can add and read cookies for your language.

Comment: @kkakkurt, Thank you for your help . i tried the mentioned solution. unfortunately i didn't work with my scenario. i just need to save and read languages in cookies that MATCHES with my scenario. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the **Asp.Net** you can set cookie like this:

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("languageKey", "languageValue"));`

and get it:

```
HttpCookie cultureCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["languageKey"];
var cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
```

and in the **JavaScript** you can use this for set cookie by JQuery:

```
$.cookie("languageKey", "yourValue");
```

and get it:

```
var languageValue = $.cookie("languageKey");
```

there are some ways to use it in the Asp.Net but the simple one is that you must override **BeginExecute** method of controller and check it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var routes = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

        string culture = (routes["culture"] ?? defaultCulture).ToString();

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("culture"))
        {
            HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("culture");
            StudentCookies.Value = culture;
            StudentCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(StudentCookies);
        }
        else
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["culture"].Value != (routes["culture"] ?? "").ToString() && routes["culture"] != null)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies["culture"].Value = (routes["culture"] ?? "").ToString();
            }
            if (routes["culture"] == null || routes["culture"] == UrlParameter.Optional)
            {
                culture = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["culture"].Value;
            }
        }

        HelperClass.SetCulture(culture);


        if (!routes.ContainsKey("culture") || routes["culture"] == UrlParameter.Optional)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/" + culture + "/" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath);
        }

        CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
        return;
    }
```